# Can't get table detail to show up

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, nsindexpath

I swear I've looked at a half-dozen tutorials and I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly. I have a tableview nested within a UIView via IB, and the table both is formatted and populates correctly. I just can't get it to show me the details screen. The table recognizes the tap, and the row is selected, but... the row stays selected. Then, absolutely nothing happens. I can selected other rows with the same results, but nothing ever happens past that. I can move in and out of the view, and have full functionality throughout the entire app. I can even scroll the tableview, but I can never get into the cell detail screen. I've linked all the necessary pieces together in IB.

This is my code for the detail view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Get the selected cell detail
    NSString *theString = [secondview objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    celldetails *dvController = [[celldetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"celldetails" bundle:nil];
    dvController.cellString = theString;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
}
```

I've tried both "bundle:nil" and "bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]", but neither produces the desired result. Anyone have a word of advice?

Comment: Does anything appear in the console log when you select the row?

Comment: As a side note, in Objective-C class names should be capitalized by convention.  So your detail view controller class "celldetails" should be named CellDetails.  Actually `CellDetailsViewController` would be clearer and would follow Apple's naming conventions more closely.

Comment: Looking in the Console Window of the Debug View, there is no output from Xcode or the simulator when I tap the cell rows. The only thing that appears is a confirmation message regarding the app closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pushViewController:animated:` doesn't do anything, your `navigationController` could be `nil`, but otherwise it should definitely work since a `UIViewController` instance sent to `pushViewController:animated:` will show some sort of visual change (unless the views are identical and you don't use animation). Try adding an `NSLog(@"blah");` line to your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` implementation, just to be sure it's getting called. Or stick a  breakpoint in that method.

A bundle of `nil` is fine. If the `.xib` was not found, then you'd get debug messages to that effect, so it's finding a `.xib`. The `.xib` even has a valid `view` outlet set since the app crashes if you load a `.xib` but no `view` outlet is set.

Comment: Well, I have a themed app with a constant background view, toolbar, and top-nav-area (no bar, though); however, I'm not convinced it's changing views to the new XIB because I still see the table and my highlighted cell selection when I tap a row in the table. There's no animation or visual cue to verify any view change has occurred.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with using UIViewController and building a UITableView through IB instead of using UITableViewController?

Comment: Yep, it could. Your `tableView` may not be being `retain`ed properly. If you use an `@property (assign)` for it, then it could be released, but controls that are already drawn can stick around after being released or deallocated. I recall being able to tap even deallocated buttons. Not sure whether that's actually going to make the delegate methods not be called or what, but I'd check that sort of thing at least. Other than that, just look at the `tableView` one more time in `IB`, *just* to make sure `delegate` and `dataSource` are both set. And do the breakpoint/log statement as well.

Comment: I just threw in a "@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;" and synthesized it but got no noticeable change in behavior. If I had any hair, I'd have pulled it all out at this point. And yes, both delegate and datasource are set to Table View. Should there be something in my "Received Actions" indicating the system recognized a tap on a cell?

Comment: Also, it just occurred to me: I'm not using a UINavBar with my UITableView. Could the UITableView Delegate be rejecting my attempt to redirect to a new view on tapping a table's cell because I'm not using a NavBar?

Comment: No, but you of course have to be using your `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController` before the `[self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:]` method will work. Just using a `UINavigationBar` means you'd have to design a manual push/pop mechanism for views, but `UINavigationController` encapsulates this for you.

Comment: Hang on. Both delegate and data source are set to `Table View`? As in, the table view is its own delegate? That's not right. The class where you write the code `tableView:didSelect..`, ie the controller which CONTAINS your table view, should be the delegate and data source. Usually, in `IB`, that's `File's Owner` if you're adding a table view to a view controller. Did you add that log/breakpoint to make sure the code was being called? I only suggested you do that because it saves time and is probably the quickest way to find out the root of the issue.

Comment: I don't like the UINavigationBar and opted not to use it. Am I not switching views because I don't have that code within my application? Regarding delegate and data source: In my ViewController, IB will only let me select "Table View", and I'm not permitted to select File's Owner. In my DetailViewController, I don't even have the option to select a delegate or datasource.

Comment: To be able to use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:]`, you have to use `UINavigationController`. See [this tutorial](http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/iosdev/navigationcontroller/) for a usage example and screenshots. If you want to do it without one, look at the [`presentViewController:animated:completion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW75) method (`iOS 5.0` and later) or the older `presentModalViewController:animated:` at the same link.

Comment: I also added programatically the UINavigationController and " [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];" and "[window makeKeyAndVisible];" to the applicationDidFiishLaunching void statement with no result...

Comment: Do it in `Interface Builder`, and make your controller with the table sit inside the navigation controller. Please use the link to the tutorial and follow that.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!! Apparently, if you don't implement a UINavigationController, the app will ignore your request to load a new view via [self.navigationController...];. I change it to [self presentModalViewController:dvController animated:YES]; and it sprang to life! Now, I just have to load the info in there! I'm pretty sure I got a handle on that one, though! Thanks for your brainstorm!

Comment: There's a rather trivial explanation for that behaviour, by the way: the `self.navigationController` property IS a `UINavigationController`, and the system doesn't create one for you. So you can't do things with a navigation controller that doesn't exist :)